# isql works but python connection fails

Tags: python, pyodbc

I'm trying to hook up odbc to work on my Mac with python via pyodbc.  I've got things set up such that

`isql -v <my Connection>`

works just file, however when I'm in a python shell and I try:

```
import pyodbc
pyodbc.connect('DSN=<my Connection>;UID=<username>;PWD=<password>
```

I get the cryptic:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', '[]  (202) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

What can I do to debug this and determine what steps I can take next to get odbc working?  Previously, I had odbc installed and was getting "no driver source name" messages in python, and after moving the odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini file to /etc, I now get the error above.  Any ideas?  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to connect to SQL Server? Give this a try:

```
DRIVER={FreeTDS};SERVER=<yourserver.example.com>;PORT=1433;DATABASE=<your DB>;UID=<your username>;<your password>;TDS_Version=7.2;
```

Hopefully, that'll work for you. The TDS version depends on what version of SQL Server you're using. See here:

http://www.freetds.org/userguide/choosingtdsprotocol.htm

7.2 also works for 2012 + 2014.

Regards,

-Tim